# Why must typeof(T) be used to get the Type when T is itself a type?

Tags: c#, typeof

e.g.

```
Type t = typeof(T);
t.GetProperty("Company")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: what programming language are you talking about?

Comment: and also use the tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: If instead of `T` you have `int` then it sounds more clear? Imagine to have the **type name** instead of your generic argument. The type definition is something else.

Comment: Hi Jaffrey...I am asking about ASP.Net C# .. e.g. in  IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList(); T is itself a Class means A Type...So why we need to find typeOf a Type..Plz help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `T` is not a `Type` object, it's just a type parameter.

At the compilation the type parameter will be replaced by an actual type. For the code generated for the `string` type for example, the `typeof(T)` will actually be `typeof(string)`. Here `string` is not a `Type` object, it's just a data type. You need the `typeof` to get the `Type` object for that data type.

Comment: ok Guffa...so u mean that typeOf(T) is giving us **Object** of Type T..is it fine said by me ??

Comment: @UmeshK.: No, `typeof(T)` gives you a `Type` object, which describes the type `T`. For example `typeof(string)` returns the same as `"".GetType()` does.

Comment: I am saying "Object of Type T" and you are saying it "Type object, which describes the type T"..so both are same things..

Comment: @UmeshK.: No, they are not the same. An object of type `T` is an instance of the class `T`, while a `Type` object is an instance of the class `System.Type`, which contains information about the type `T`. `typeof(T)` returns an instance of the class `Type`, while `new T()` creates an instance of the class `T`.

Comment: yes.. e.g. int radius = 3;
            Type t = radius.GetType(); returns INT32 thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a difference between a type, and an object *describing* a type.

`T` is a type. `typeof` is applied to a type, and returns an object of type `Type`, which *describes* the type in question.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt to explain the difference:

There are compile time types, like `string`, `int` or `MyClass`. You declared them when you write your code.

There are runtime types. They are hold in objects of type `Type`. These are normal object instances that exist in memory at runtime. You get such an object by typeof(`MyType`). These type objects can be used to examine types at runtime.